# Php MySQL - Delete all rows by limit

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete all rows expect the 5 first rows.

```
/*example of the $count is equal to 5 */
$count=$xml->table->records->attributes();
```

This is my table:

```
xml_id  
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
```

The result would be like this

```
xml_id  
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

The above 5 will be deleted.

Comment: Are the IDs that you want to keep always going to be 1-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

```
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE xml_id  NOT IN
    (SELECT xml_id  
     FROM Table1
     LIMIT 5)
```